# How to make cached ajax request obsolete after logout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http-caching

I am performing an AJAX call with the following settings:

```
  headers: {
                'Cache-Control': 'max-age=30,private' 
            }
```

The server response is:

```
 Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Private);
            Response.Cache.SetMaxAge(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(0.5));
```

Like I expected, the browser stores the response for 30 seconds.

However, after signing out I want to drop that cache - I want to clean the cache in order to support a different logged-on user in the near future.

I do not want to add a user specific key to the request.
Are there any other possibilities?

Comment: Well written first question mate. Welcome to StackOverflow (+1)

Answer (score 1):

in global.asax.cs, Application_BeginRequest method add below code

```
Response.AppendHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
Response.AppendHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
Response.AppendHeader("Expires", "0");
```

Comment: Thx, but does this prevent http caching on client side? At least "no-cach" implicates this to me..?

Comment: and isn't this possible to define on controller action level?

Comment: Yes, this will prevent http caching on client side. u can define it on controller action level. place above code in sign out functionality.

Comment: Hmm actually I didn't find any solution yet. I tried 
            HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
            HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches);
            HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetMaxAge(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));
            HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetSlidingExpiration(true);                in the controller action, whose repsonse I dont want to be stored after signing out but chrome still caches the request for the next 2 minutes